# Is compatible classic tube and classic tire (27.5x2.1) with tubeless ready rim(27.5x2.1)?

Tags: tire, rims, innertube, tubeless

Is compatible **classic tube** and **classic tire** (27.5x2.1) with **tubeless ready rim**(27.5x2.1)?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This would be easier to answer if you could give us the exact make/model of tire and rim.